# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Sendgrid

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email, mongoose, sendgrid

I have a question. I am trying to program a backend which gets an request from client site and the server response is an email. Also I want to save the data in an DB. Basically I have a form on the client site and I just want to save the data and send the data via email to the user. The strange thing is, it is working, but I am getting also this answer:

> »Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client«

Could someone give me maybe a hint why it is like this?

```
const Briefing = require("../models/briefing");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.EMAIL_API_KEY);

exports.briefing = (req, res) => {
  const {
    gender,
    age,
    income,
  } = req.body;

  let newBriefing = new Briefing({
    gender,
    age,
    income,
  });

  newBriefing.save((err, success) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR CREATING BRIEFING", err);
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    res.json({
      message: "Briefing successfull created",
    });
  });

  const emailData = {
    to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
    from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    subject: `Briefing`,
    text: "Eine Aufstellung des erstellten Briefings",
    html: `
        <h1>Das Briefing</h1>
        <p>Vielen dank, dass du dir die Zeit genommen hast dieses Briefing zu erstellen.</p>
        <p>Hier vorab die Daten:</p>
        <p>${gender}</p>
        <p>${age}</p>
        <p>${income}</p>
        <p>desweiteren befindet sich im anhang eine PDF</p>
      `,
  };

  sgMail
    .send(emailData)
    .then((send) => {
      console.log("SIGNUP EMAIL SEND", send);
      return res.json({
        message: `Email has been sent to social@moritzwright.com follow the instruction to activate your account.`,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("EMAIL SENDING ERROR", err);
      console.error(err.response.body);
    });
};
```

Comment: you can only respond to an http response once. if you want to push constant updates to your client you'll have to setup a socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem in taking the process of sending the email after the if statement, like this:

```
const Briefing = require("../models/briefing");
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.EMAIL_API_KEY);

exports.briefing = (req, res) => {
  const {
    gender,
    age,
    income,
  });

  newBriefing.save((err, success) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR CREATING BRIEFING", err);
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    const emailData = {
      to: process.env.EMAIL_TO,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      subject: `Briefing`,
      text: "Eine Aufstellung des erstellten Briefings",
      html: `
            <h1>Das Briefing</h1>
            <p>Vielen dank, dass du dir die Zeit genommen hast dieses Briefing zu erstellen.</p>
            <p>Hier vorab die Daten:</p>
            <p>${gender}</p>
            <p>${age}</p>
            <p>${income}</p>
            <p>desweiteren befindet sich im anhang eine PDF</p>
          `,
    };

    sgMail
      .send(emailData)
      .then((send) => {
        console.log("SIGNUP EMAIL SEND", send);
        return res.json({
          message: `Email has been sent to social@moritzwright.com follow the instruction to activate your account.`,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("EMAIL SENDING ERROR", err);
        console.error(err.response.body);
      });
  });
};
```